# How does pd.concat work with pd.NA values in multiIndex ? Sometimes rows are dropped, sometimes rows are duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, na

I get unexpected results when I concatenate some of my DataFrames. Since my endless attempts to isolate the cause of the problem - assuming there is one - have been unsuccessful so far, here I am. I use Pandas v1.4.2.

**First issue:**
I horizontally concatenate two multiIndex dataframes. Both have at least one row whose multiIndex is (pd.NA, pd.NA). The output dataframe misses one row. Why ?

Illustration:

```
test_B  = pd.DataFrame([19,18,17,16,15,14, 13, pd.NA], columns=['predictionB'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1.0, 1.0),(2.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, pd.NA), (3.0, 1.0),(4.0, 1.0),(4.0, 2.0),(pd.NA, pd.NA)], names=["first", "second"]))

test_B
             predictionB
first second            
1.0   1.0             19
2.0   1.0             18
      2.0             17
      NaN             16
3.0   1.0             15
4.0   1.0             14
      2.0             13
NaN   NaN           <NA>
```

and

```
test_Z  = pd.DataFrame([pd.NA,18,17,16,15,14, 13, 9, 11], columns=['predictionZ'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1.0, pd.NA),(2.0, pd.NA), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 1.0),(4.0, 1.0),(4.0, 2.0),(pd.NA, pd.NA), (pd.NA, 3.0)], names=["first", "second"]))

             predictionZ
first second            
1.0   NaN           <NA>
2.0   NaN             18
      2.0             17
      3.0             16
3.0   1.0             15
4.0   1.0             14
      2.0             13
NaN   NaN              9
      3.0             11
```

then:

```
pd.concat([test_B, test_Z], axis=1).sort_index()
```

gives:

```
             predictionB predictionZ
first second                        
1.0   1.0             19         NaN
      NaN            NaN        <NA>
2.0   1.0             18         NaN
      2.0             17          17
      NaN             16          18
3.0   1.0             15          15
4.0   1.0             14          14
      2.0             13          13
NaN   NaN           <NA>           9
```

Two questions:

1. Since a NaN (pd.NA) is different from any other NaN (pd.NA), then why does pd.concat put the pd.NA and the 9 on the same row?
2. And why did the row with (NaN, 3.0) disappear? It's a concatenation, I would expect to see all the index keys of my inputs into my outputs.

**Second issue:**

At some point in my code, some groupby generate dataframes which also have pd.NA on several levels of their respective multiIndex. When I concatenate these dataframes, no rows are dropped, but those whose index are (pd.NA, pd.NA) are duplicated.

Illustration:

```
uuu_1
one  two
4.0  3.0    22
     4.0    44
NaN  1.0    14
     2.0     2
     4.0     6
     NaN    15
Name: providerA, dtype: int64


uuu_2
one  two
3.0  3.0     30
     4.0     53
4.0  2.0      8
     3.0     20
     4.0     99
NaN  NaN     12
Name: providerB, dtype: int64


pd.concat([uuu_1, uuu_2], axis=1).sort_index()
         providerA  providerB
one two                      
3.0 3.0        NaN       30.0
    4.0        NaN       53.0
4.0 2.0        NaN        8.0
    3.0       22.0       20.0
    4.0       44.0       99.0
NaN 1.0       14.0        NaN
    2.0        2.0        NaN
    4.0        6.0        NaN
    NaN       15.0       12.0
    NaN       15.0       12.0
```

I would have expected either an output df such that one row shows
(NaN, NaN) 15.0 NaN, where 15.0 would be in column providerA and NaN in column providerB,
and another row shows
(NaN, NaN) NaN 12.0 where NaN would be in column providerA and 12.0 in column providerB
or a df showing 15.0 and 12.0 on the same row, given all the above. Not two duplicated rows with both values on each.

Here, not only are 15.0 and 12.0 on the same row, but that row is also duplicated. Why ?

I replaced the NaN by strings, and the problem is gone. But why do I get duplicated rows if I keep the pd.NA ? I would like to understand this.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket on GitHub; it seems to be an old known bug...
As of September 2022, avoid concatenating dataframes whose indexes contain pd.NA.
A workaround consists in replacing them by strings.

See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48852
and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37222

I don't understand why there is no warning about that in the doc. Doesn't make sense to me.